# nodejs Javascript execution environment for react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a react native application where I would like to host the js code on heroku and serve a console client.

react native has a module packager which packages the files and serves the single bundle. When we say /index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&minify=false&dev=true this returns the bundled package.

In a typical native application the js execution environment would be the device itself.

For chrome debugging the js execution environment is the chrome.

For this application, neither do I have access to native mobile nor do I have access to chrome, so what will the execution environment.

I thought of creating a proxy node server where javascript execution environment would be node but apparently node js cannot run the bundled react native javascript file (i.e, index.ios.bundle). It fails with following error.

```
assert.js:85
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
  ^
AssertionError: path must be a string
    at Module.require (module.js:496:3)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sabertooth/temp/react-server.js:68664:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
```

The specific line of code where it fails

```
;require(216);
```

Comment: index.ios.bundle seems to be packaged for browser, not for nodejs. They have some differences, assert belonging to them. Maybe there is a nodejs packaged version? If not and if you only have no access to chrome's GUI, you could try using `chrome --headless`.